# Change asp message box header / title

Tags: asp.net, messagebox

How can I change the title of my message box 
[image]

Here is my code-behind:

```
 string myStringVariable1 = string.Empty;
                    myStringVariable1 = "Policy Number:" + "  " + txtPolNo.Text.ToString() + "  " + "with Issuance office:" + "  " + dropIssOff.Text.ToString() + "  " + "was not found on the database. Please make sure that your inputs are correct.";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable1 + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 4):

No, You can't change that title. Alternatively you can use the [jQuery alert/dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) to achieve the same.